# MySql, where clause filter off entries even with LEFT join

Tags: mysql, sql

3 tables: classes, students and class_student (association table). Following query output student count of each class. When there is no students in a class, the count(..) is 0 but class name is still in result.

```
select c.name, count(s.id)
from classes c
    left join
  class_student cs on cs.classId = c.id
    left join
  students s on s.id = cs.studentId
group by c.id;
```

Now want to count students with score 100% of each class so a WHERE is added:

```
select c.name, count(s.id)
from classes c
    left join
  class_student cs on cs.classId = c.id
    left join
  students s on s.id = cs.studentId
where s.score = 100  <-- newly added
group by c.id;
```

then the classes that do not have any 100% students do not show up in the result. Considering LEFT JOIN is used, I'm expecting count(s.id) returns 0 when there is no 100% students. How can I make all classes are in result and those without any 100% student have count(..) output 0. Thanks

Comment: The two duplicate questions show two different solutions: move the filter criteria into the join condition or use conditional counting.

Answer (score 1):

The extra condition should be placed in the `ON` clause instead of the `WHERE` clause, as in:

```
select c.name, count(s.id)
from classes c
    left join
  class_student cs on cs.classId = c.id
    left join
  students s on s.id = cs.studentId
            and s.score = 100  <-- newly added
group by c.id;
```

If you place it in a `WHERE` clause you are essentially defeating the outer join and converting it automatically into an inner join (as you did unintentionally).

Comment: Thank you man for answering in less than 30 seconds after my posting. It solves the issue.